# Object&pointer representation of graphs

Tags: data-structures, tree, graph-algorithm

Looking 
into representations of graphs, the representation with 
objects&pointers 
is favorable to the adjacency-list representation and adjacency-matrix representation 
when the graph is a tree of type 
n-ary, binary (ordinary binary, balanced-- red-black, AVL, etc) trie, b-tree, ... , and obviously not a heap. 
This is because:

1.) in a tree structure, the edges have distinct meanings-- "left-child", 
"right-child", "parent", "i-th child" in b-trees, 
the link value in tries/radix trees, etc. 
Tree operations require the traversal of a specific link-- based on the link types 
(left-,  right-, .. i-th-child, etc). 
The use of pointers can easily allow to distinguish the link types. 
Adjacency list representation would require an extra field on the 
link-node to tell what kind of a link it is. 
Matrix representation would require coded matrix entries to tell what kind of a link it is.

2.) Tree operations often require moving around the subtrees of a node. 
This can easily be done, 
in constant time, by changing the pointer values. 
In an adjacency list and matrix representations, 
this operation would take searching for the link-to-be altered 
in the edge-list of the nodes and is linear in the number of edges or the graph degree-- no longer in O(1).

The object&pointer representation of a tree can be backed by array structures:
So, each vertex is 
still represented by an object. This object has a pointer to each child and one 
to the parent (whichever the way the tree being implemented calls for). 
But this time, the objects are array entries, and the pointer values are array indices. This is a mix of adjacency-list and objects&pointers representations of graphs 
and is powerful.

My Q is: What other general cases are there in the representations of graphs 
where the representation with objects&pointers is preferable to the adjacency-list 
representation and to the the adjacency-matrix
representation?

I'm looking for references to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's "the representations with objects&pointers"? It's not a standard term AFAIK, so you'll have to define it.

Comment: @delnan known as well as adjacency list & adjacency matrix representations. look-up binary trees at CLRS-- see how the tree structure is worked. look around.

Comment: No, that term is not know at all in the circles I frequent, even though I'm very familiar with the typical implementations of trees. Based on that I can guess what you mean, but it's really just a guess and an informal notion. Also, if I were to treat these tree structures as graphs, I would consider the typical tree implementation as just another case of adjacency lists. One with fixed length and fancy names for the individual list elements, but still an adjacency list.

Comment: @delnan well - as i said, look around some. doing the tree on an adj.list wd be showing your right ear wit hyour left arm.